Having issues with with “Drag & Drop” with Kali Linux on VirtualBox: “DnD: Error: Requesting pending data from guest failed (VERR_TIMEOUT).”
I have an issue with “Drag & Drop” with Kali Linux on VirtualBox on a Debian host!
Details:
Drag and drop operation from guest to host failed.
   
  DnD: Error: Requesting pending data from guest failed (VERR_TIMEOUT).
    
  Result Code:VBOX_E_DND_ERROR (0X80BB0011)
  Component:GuestDnDSourceWrap
  Interface:IGuestDnDSource {dedfb5d9-4c1b-edf7-fdf3-c1be6827dc28}
  Callee:IDnDSource {d23a9ca3-42da-c94b-8aec-21968e08355d}

Kali Linux version:

6.6.9-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Kali 6.6.9-1kali1 (2024-01-08) x86_64 GNU/Linux

VirtualBox “Guest Additions” Version:

7.0.14_Debianr161095

What I tried:

I tried reinstalling Guest Additions and rebooting
Changing both “Drag & Drop” and clipboard to ridirectional and then rebooting.

Here is VirtualBox’s log on PasteBin:

https://pastebin.com/vByFaPLk

